# How to create mongodb 2dsphere index on strapi?

Tags: mongodb, strapi

My **strapi** project use Mongo database.

Strapi version : 3.0.0-beta.19.5

I have tried :

- creating the **2dsphere** index manually with the command in the mongo console, but when the application start to run, the index got deleted. I think maybe the database kinda synchronize with the **strapi** model configuration.
- I checked the [strapi document](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/models.html#model-options)  and I see there is an option to create an index by adding a configuration to the **model.settings.json**, but there is only a **single field index** option.

Is there any way to create a **2dspere index**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a solution. I had to look up on the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) **index part**.

In strapi documentation, they only tell that the value of **'index'** is a **boolean** type. Which is different from mongoose doc. Actually the **model.settings.json** structure follow mongoose documentation.

So, to create the 2dsphere index we just need to specify "2dsphere" in the key "index" on that field.

Eg.

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "connection": "default",
  "collectionName": "phone_stores",
  "info": {
    "name": "phoneStore"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true
  },
  "attributes": {
    "car": {
      "type": "integer",
      "required": true
    },
    "userStoreId": {
      "type": "objectId"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "json",
      "index": "2dsphere" // <------ <1>
    },
  }
}
```

**<1>**   if true were specify, [Single field index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) will be created on this field. But u can also specify other type of [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/), like in my case i use '2dsphere'.

**UPDATE**

What I said about

> u can also specify other type of index

is not correct. The index type is limited because of the framework. So far I have test with `2dsphere`, which is working. I test also `text` index, but it didn't work.